# How do you create a dependency for a session that depends on another session?

Tags: session, meteor

I would like to know how to re-run a computation.

The way my functions are set up currently do no reactively update the UI.

I used `_.extend` to extend documents from two different collections. On the left of the UI is a list of *names*.

Upon a click event of a particular *name*, `Session.set('extendedDoc', this)` is created. Logging this in the console displays the selected 'extended' document - fine.

A helper returns the selected extended doc to display all document contents

```
displaySelectedExtendedDoc: function() {
    return Session.get('extendedDoc');
}
```

After an update takes place within this document, the UI is not updated unless the the *name* is clicked. ie: setting the session `Session.set('extendedDoc', this)`.

How can UI be reactively updated.

I am sourcing http://robertdickert.com/blog/2013/11/14/why-is-my-meteor-app-not-updating-reactively/
and http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun but struggling to grasp exactly how to set up a reactive context

```
Session.set('extendedDoc', this) depends on a Collection.find(_id: Session.get('ANOTHER_SESSION_VALUE))
```

Comment: It seems like a transform (either on the whole collection or on a find) could be a better solution than using session variables. Can you explain the actual problem in more detail?

Comment: transform is not reactive, but not using session variables is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you store a document in session and you return the session in your helper. You can return the document in your helper instead of session:

```
displaySelectedExtendedDoc: function() {
    return Collection.findOne(Session.get('ANOTHER_SESSION_VALUE));
}
```

Comment: Tomas, this solved the problem. The helper returning a cursor maintains reactivity. I put my findOne call within a #with helper so the join happens reactively on page. I made a few adjustments to my code and now its reactive. Super!